# Asking git to look for different key other than id_rsa

Tags: git, ssh, github

I not sure why but even though I mention properly in ssh config to look for identity file with name viren.pub  for github

git still considering id_rsa as default and it does not seem to work unless an until i rename **viren.pub** and **viren** to **id_rsa.pub** and **id_rsa**

Here my ssh config look like

```
Host ec2-123-121-121-121.compute-1.amazonaws.com
        Hostname github.com
        User git
        IdentityFile /root/.ssh/viren
```

Can anyone help

Comment: did you add ssh config file entry written in your question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the ssh config only applies if you use the alias defined in `host` clause to connect to the server.

I.e. you should have in ssh config have:

```
host github
    hostname github.com
    user git
    identityfile /root/.ssh/viren
```

The `host` directive has to be followed with something you will actually use to connect, so `[Amazon server]` is not appropriate. And you have to tell git to connect to:

```
github:/....
```

(and not `git@github.com:/.....`)

Comment: what do mean ? I already have a host define in my .ssh/config as I mention it an amazon server ec2-123-121-121-121.compute-1.amazonaws.com . Let me know what I'm doing wrong

Comment: @Viren: Pardon me? You have a section in `.ssh/config` that has `host ec2-123-121-121-121.compute-1.amazonaws.com` and `hostname github.com`? That's not how it works. The `host` defines alias for the following `hostname` directive, so it should be the same or abbreviation of the following hostname.

Comment: Thanks Man you must be sure on this but y then specify host as github is not working for me

Comment: got it I guess it  should be github.com and not github

Comment: JFI can i set mutiple identity file for same host like example github

Comment: @Viren: You have to identify the host by what is written after the `host` directive (note, that there may actually be multiple names there and all should work).

Comment: that great does that also answer that i can have multiple identify file for a specific host

Comment: @Viren: Yes, you can have any number of sections with different `host` and the same value `hostname` and the same or different value for any other option as you need.

Comment: Thanks Man Was of great help truly appreciate

Comment: @Viren there's a specific example of this usage in my answer over at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763410/can-ssh-add-be-added-globally/10904314#10904314