# can ssh-add be added globally

Tags: git, ssh, github, ssh-keys, openssh

Can I do **ssh-add** against the **identifyFile** that stay forever, currently it prevail only for the current active **ssh session** (i.e identityFile added using ssh-add get lost when a new ssh session is made with the server can be found by running ssh-add -L )

The problem is that our amazon server has various projects with repo resting in github.

Now each one of the repo has **access right based on the users**
say **user A has access right only for project A** and **B has an access right on project B** only

With that access right set(in github) now each user can perform git operation(like git fetch, git push etc) only to there **respective project** (which is what we want)

Now all I want is when a user perform a git operation on there respective project I want **ssh-agent** to take all ssh-keys in accounts and look for the one that match to that specific users

**Note**

> that each ssh-key has a  phrases(a unique secret know to each user there own) associated with it, prompted to enter when perform git function.

to achieve this we do

```
ssh-add /root/.ssh/A
```

**or**

```
ssh-add /root/.ssh/B
```

But as mention earlier this only stay for the **active ssh-session** ,**exit** or make a **new** ssh session with the server the ssh-add info is **lost**. can be found by running **ssh-add -L**

I have also tried defining IdentityFile in .ssh/config like this describe in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10698167/asking-git-to-look-for-different-key-other-than-id-rsa)

something like this

```
Host github.com
        Hostname github.com
        User git
        IdentityFile /root/.ssh/A

Host github.com
        Hostname github.com
        User git
        IdentityFile /root/.ssh/B
```

This only work for one user (sometime it work for 'A' and sometime it doesnt ,same is with 'B' too)

Can this segregation be achieved or am I sounding a bit over ambitious

Thanks

Comment: Can you edit your question and say (at the end) exactly what you are trying to do?  The reason I ask is there is likely a simple way to solve it, but we need to know your objective.  Your current method is not so good and needs replaced!

Comment: @gahooa Edited let me know if it still required further editing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're very close with your edit of the IdentityFile. However, you need to have **unique** hostnames listed in the IdentityFile. Because you used github.com as the hostname both times, when you try to connect to github.com, it has no idea which one to use.

We have a similar setup. We have 5 users, all of whom log in to a single account. However, Github needs to see them each using their own ssh-key, so we have 5 keys. The trick to get around this is to make your file look like this

```
Host UserA_github
        Hostname github.com
        User git
        IdentityFile /root/.ssh/A

Host UserB_github
        Hostname github.com
        User git
        IdentityFile /root/.ssh/B
```

Whenever *UserB* wants to do something git related, (e.g. clone one of their repositories) they will run...

```
git clone UserB_github:UserB/MyRepo
```

or something similar. This will behave as if they had entered...

```
git clone github.com:UserB/MyRepo
```

except that it will use the appropriate IdentityFile/private key.

I understand that my solution doesn't use a persistent `ssh-add` but I think this will give you the same performance that you want. Unfortunately, your users will need to enter their passphrase each time they perform a transaction.

Comment: Of course, multiple users sharing a single account is probably not ideal from a security perspective, but sometimes there are reasons to go this route.

Comment: Thanks just give couple of hours or so to test this and I will definitely accept the answer then