# Log in to GitHub from the command line with multiple accounts

Tags: git, github

I opened a new GitHub account to separate my business vs. personal repositories.

Now, I `git init` my local repository and `git add remote origin <the repository HTTPS URL>`

I try to push, and it seems to always take the credentials of my original account, not prompting me for the credentials for the new account.

I tried using the URL format with

```
https://<username>:<password>@github.com/<username>/<repository.git>
```

but that doesn't seem to help: I still get an error that the credentials are invalid for the original account username.

How do I log in with multiple sets of credentials or how would I somehow reset the original credentials to force password prompt when pushing?

---

The only way I managed to push right now is by specifying the `username:password@github.com/` in the URL in the `git push` command.

Comment: As an alternative, you could use ssh keys to effectively have the same remote but for different users, e.g. (server/personal server/biz would resolve to same URL, but use different accounts); see answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10904314/288545)

Comment: yes i know i can do that. It is just not so convenient especially with submodules etc... as others may not use the same hostname format. submodules in a repo require the url of the submodule repo. if I set it to my hostname in ssh_config, others get that info and won't be able to pull unless they set their own ssh_config the same way. Just a pain.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The only way I managed to push was by specifying the `username:password@github.com/` in the URL in the Git push command.

Comment: By what if my password happens to have an @ symbol?

Comment: FYI this(pwd authent) no longer supported by Github

Comment: as a side note: I'd strongly discourage using multiple accounts, rather add any other email to your account and add a ssh key for each machine you use, and you'll be much better off, as you can keep all history of commits / activity from all emails, even if you lose access to them (i.e. company email)

Comment: @BadrBellaj It is still supported, you just need to replace the `password` with the token provided by Github

Answer (score 26):

```
git config --global credential.helper cache
```

... which tells git to keep your password cached in memory for (by default) 15 minutes.  You can [set a longer timeout](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/v1.7.9/git-credential-cache.html#_examples) with:

```
git config --global credential.helper "cache --timeout=3600"
```

More useful links:

https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/permanently-authenticating-with-git-repositories-776639846.html

> Using the .netrc file
>   The .netrc file is a mechanism that allows you to specify which credentials to use for which server.
>
> This method allows you to avoid entering a username and password every time you push to or pull from Git, but your Git password is stored in plain text.

---

You can store your credentials using the following command

```
git config credential.helper store
git push http://example.com/repo.git
# Now type username and password and it should be saved by git.
```

Comment: I did comment that it is not convenient for me . I want to figure how to reset or force password prompt.

Comment: Ok, you can save the credentials in  git config if that what you mean.

Comment: tried that too, but keep getting the error :
`remote: Permission to <newUsername>/repo.git denied to <originalUsername>.`
I do not get prompted for a password.

Comment: when i do `git config credential.helper store` it just returns. Not sure if that is normal. I never get prompted for the password for this account.

Comment: And what happened on the second time? prompt again?

Comment: never get a password prompt. I just tried `git config --global credential.helper "cache --timeout=10"` but even past the 10sec i don't get prompted, just get a 403

Comment: I did all kind of stuff too and it doesn't prompt me for password either. Always Permission denied to XXX.

Comment: This answer doesn't work. How is it the most upvoted?

Comment: Maybe because you did something wrong?

Answer (score 12):

### Using SSH Credentials on Unix or Mac

1. Configure Git in your workspace
2. Make/check SSH credentials
3. Update Online Github settings

#### Step 1. Configure Git in your Workspace

1. In your shell, add your user name: `git config --global user.name "your_username"`
2. Add your email address: `git config --global user.email "your_email_address@example.com"`
3. To check the configuration, run: `git config --global --list`

#### Step 2: Make SSH Credentials

1. Open bash or Terminal.
2. `cd ~/.ssh`
3. `ls`
4. There should be these two files: id_rsa and id_rsa.pub. These are login credentials.
5. If the email in id_rsa.pub does not match the email you want to use, then make new credentials. To keep things simple, use 'id_rsa' for the file in which to save the key and make a passphrase to save for later
   `ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your_email@example.com"`
6. Save your passphrase somewhere safe to use when you push, or you will need to do this again.

#### Step 3: Update Online Github Settings

1. `vim ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`
2. Copy the contents of id_rsa.pub and paste it into GitHub [website](https://github.com/settings/keys) under the Account Settings > SSH and GPG Keys. Copy all of it, exactly as it appears, with no extra spaces or lines. Give these credentials a name to remind you which machine it is from.
3. Try *git push* again

#### Troubleshooting

If you get a warning about permissions being too open `Permissions 0644` then try these:

- Set the permissions on your private key: `chmod 400 ~/.ssh/id_rsa`
- Make sure `~/.ssh/config` points to the correct private key

#### References

- [Configure Git](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/gitlab-basics/start-using-git.html#configure-git)
- [Fix Permissions](https://gist.github.com/adamjohnson/5682757)
- [Connecting to GitHub with SSH](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh)

Answer (score 5):

You can use the Git configuration inside the repository you are using. In `${local_repo_folder}/.git/config`, add your user details there. That way you can configure which user to use on a per-repository level.

Comment: I did try to add `user.username` and `user.password` to the git config:
first it didn't help, and 2nd i don't like to have this info in a file that is easily readable. But if you know a way to do it that works, I'd be glad to check it out.

Comment: it would help if you showed an example configuration.

Comment: Do not do this.

Comment: Be aware that your password will be stored as plain text.

Answer (score 4):

Use this command to relogin with a different account on GitHub:

```
git remote set-url origin "remote repository URL"
```

Answer (score 2):

In Github I went to Settings | Developer Settings | Tokens (classic) and generated a new token. (Link is https://github.com/settings/tokens)

When I clone a new repository, I use a token, e.g.

```
git clone https://USERNAME:TOKEN@bitbucket.org/workspaceID/reposlug.git
```

Once I've done this, it lets me push to Github without using the token.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs:

> If you omit --global or use --local, the configuration is applied only to the current repository.

In your shell, add your user name:

```
git config user.name "your_username"
```

And your email address:

```
git config user.email "your_email_address@example.com"
```

To check the configuration, run:

```
git config --list
```

And to compare to your global configuration, run:

```
git config --global --list
```

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/gitlab-basics/start-using-git.html

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is deprecated.

Alternatively you can try

git push https://user@github.com/user/repo.git

then provide in the prompt the token generated in github

or add to github/localSsh your ssh key as indicated in here

https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent?platform=linux

Answer (score 1):

## Config multiple accounts on Mac, Linux and bash in Window

You are looking for configuring multiple account git using on your local machine. I will provide a solution used for Mac, Linux and Window using bash.

Be awared before start, **your_email@example.com** would be your email to be added in github developer setting later, **your_email_2@example.com** is used for testing in cased abort pushing to remotely.

In your project, remember to set **config** up

```
// You will need setting for this email in ssh later
git config user.email "your_email@example.com"
git config user.name "some_name"
```

Firstly, **[generate your own](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent)** ssh within your **email**

```
ssh-keygen -t -C "your_email@example.com"
```

And then it will ask you **where to locate** this generated key:

```
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/some-user/.ssh/id_rsa):
```

You can **custom** the **generate path** file as you wish to, for example:

```
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/some-user/.ssh/id_rsa): /home/some-user/.ssh/first-key
```

In this example, I will generate **two pai**r, first for your_email@example.com & second for your_email_2@example.com

```
First would be: id_rsa // Account: your_email, email: your_email@example.com
Second would be: first-key // Account: your_email_2, email: your_email_2@example.com
```

And then just simply accept other options, then you will have a pair private, public key. You can check in .ssh folder by:

```
cd ~/.ssh && ls -a
```

Now you would see in your terminal your pair, look something like:

```
 id_rsa.pub  id_rsa
 // And first-key
 first-key.pub first-key
```

Then you would need to **add these pub keys** into the **developer setting** in your github: https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account

Now last but not least, you need to setting up your **ssh config** so that when you push your code, **ssh can detect which account** you are using and then will point to the correct file

```
cd ~/.ssh
touch config // If not have
nano config // Or using Vim
```

And now you need to paste the following config

```
\\ When you clone via ssh, your remote url would be in this format:
\\ git clone git@github.com:githubAccountName/repoName.git

\\ Edit in config file of .ssh
\\ Host github.com 
\\  HostName github.com 
\\  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_personal 
\\  User githubAccountName


Host github.com 
    HostName github.com 
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa // Your path point to private key
    User your_email // Put your account here

Host github.com 
    HostName github.com 
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/first-key // Your second account
    User your_email_2 // Put your account or email here
```

Now you can try with your **your_emai**l as you **added** your key in **developer settings**, if you change your config to your_email_2, you cannot push to remote because you haven't add your ssh-key yet.

```
// You will need setting for this email in ssh later
git config user.email "your_email_2@example.com"
git config user.name "some_name_2"
```

For more reference, you can take a look at this if my answer doesn't help: https://gist.github.com/jexchan/2351996

Answer (score 0):

Since authentication using username & password has been discontinued by Github since August 2021, we can authenticate only through SSH key or Personal Access Token.
I tried the Personal Access Token option. But while using `git push` command, there was no prompt to enter the PAT. Here's what worked for me(Windows 10).

In your cmd/Git Bash/power shell, enter

```
git config user.name "your_username"
git config user.email "your_email"
```

After doing this go to Credential Manager, and update the credential for Github with the new username & password.
[Demo Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1l6qZ.png)

Now, if you try the `git push` command, it will prompt you to enter your PAT for authentication.
You can generate your PAT by going to your [Github profile]->Settings->Developer settings.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to go to Control Panel > User Accounts > Manage Your Credentials > Windows Credentials and then look for git:https://github.com. Then click the drop down arrow besides it and click Remove.

Then, run the command git push -u origin master and it will ask you to login via the Web Browser. Enter your credentials on the GitHub website that pops-up and grant permissions and you are good to go!

Answer (score -1):

But I have an idea, log into Github:

one via terminal, the other via Github Desktop APP.